# Problem with scrolling inside flexbox container CSS

Tags: css

I've been trying to make a scrollable div, containing images.

But it seems to not work properly since div with overflow property exceeds the width of parent div.

**Code:**

```css
div.displayWrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

div.displayWrapper div.navigationWrapper,
div.adminBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

div.displayWrapper div.navigationWrapper div.imagesBox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  outline: 1px solid black;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<asp:MultiView id="globalMultiView" runat="server">
  <asp:View id="globalMainView" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel id="imgUpdatePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:MultiView id="imagesMultiView" runat="server">
          <asp:View id="imagesDisplayView" runat="server">
            <div class="displayWrapper">
              <div class="navigationWrapper">
                <div class="imagesBox">
                  <asp:Repeater id="rptDisplaySet" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <asp:LinkButton id="linkChoice" OnCommand="ManagePreviewCommand" CommandName='<%# (string)Eval("ImageName") %>' runat="server">
                        <img src='<%# ResolveUrl(System.IO.Path.Combine(DataCatalog, (string)Eval("ImageName"))) %>' alt='<%# (string)Eval("ImageName") %>' title='<%# (string)Eval("ImageName") %>' />
                      </asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
```

I've tried different options, but nothing works correctly.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAsiE.png)
[DebuggerTool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JahhF.png)

Comment: Can you also share your HTML code?

Comment: Give us please an example with code that does not work in order to be able to help you.

Comment: @TannerDolby surely

Comment: @the_curious_one try like this `overflow-y: scroll;` and  `div.displayWrapper div.navigationWrapper div.imagesBox  {flex-wrap: wrap; }`

Comment: @TannerDolby I've just edited the post

Comment: I see that your using ASP.NET, so I'm not able to reproduce your HTML/CSS code. Could you include a screenshot of the page and issue so we could tailor a solution for you?

Comment: @TannerDolby yes

Comment: @TannerDolby the screen's been added

Comment: Ok perfect. So do you want the row images to be scrollable horizontally? Or for them to wrap onto the next line when it overflows the parent container?

Comment: @TannerDolby I want to scroll images horizontally. Try some examples that I found on internet, but gaven't reach the desirable result.

Comment: @Husna why overflow-y???

Comment: @the_curious_one To make div vertically scrollable. If you want horizontal scroll then use overflow-x

Comment: @Husna you're right, but as I mentioned before I need vertical scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of using [CSS Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) to create a row of images that are scrollable horizontally. From the picture you included, it seems that the row of images is overflowing out of the parent container.

As there aren't any explicit `width` declarations in the stylesheet you included, it's tough to say what exactly is causing your error without seeing a runnable demo in a JSFiddle or ASP sandbox environment.

```css
.parent {
  border: .1rem solid #f06;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.image-row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.image-row img {
  border: .15rem solid #333;
  margin: 0 .25rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="parent">
  <div class="image-row">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
    <img src="https://i.ibb.co/KyVGw3J/Screen-Shot-2021-02-15-at-1-32-04-AM.png" alt="tiger" width="200" height="150">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The code above definitely works as we can use the runnable code snippet to see. But it seems your parent container that your nesting the image row container inside of is the root of the problem. I added a container to hold the row of images so you should make sure your local project has similar layout/styling and it should work fine.

Comment: maybe, I'll take a look

Comment: The above example works perfectly fine, there must be something wrong in your code that is allowing the row of images to overflow. Can you include a screenshot of the parent container that holds the images in Developer Tools within your browser so we can attempt to debug that way?

Comment: I added the screen of debugger tool

Comment: Ok I just had a look, you can remove that picture as it's not very helpful by itself. Can you replace it with an image of the parent container inspected with the row of images in it so I can see the styles applied and where the issue is more clearly.

Comment: maybe the reason is thet flex resizes to fit it's content????

Comment: I meant a larger screenshot where we can see the webpage and the CSS styles. As you can see in my example above, there shouldn't be any issue using flexbox as it won't overflow a parent container unless it has an explicit `width` declaration causing it to overflow. If you don't already, give the container with the row of images a `margin: 0 auto` like I used in my above example to make sure margin isn't whats causing the issue if there isn't a explicit width.

Comment: it's no margin, but when I commented two first styles the width adjusted to the parent